# What is the site that shows all the tokens I own in my Ethereum 0x... address across all other L2 EVM compatible chains?

Tags: evm, addresses

Is there a site that shows all the tokens I own in my Ethereum address along with all the L2 EVM compatible chains?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out https://zerion.io/

It won't show every single token possible, but shows most every token that has tradable value (including NFTs)

Answer (score 0):

Try https://zapper.fi/

I use this all the time to view my portfolio across multiple chains